# How to set before_action on omniauth callback?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth

I need to set the header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` for the OmniAuth callback action. How do I do that? OmniAuth apparently doesn't use my `ApplicationController`.

Comment: Do you have `omniauth_controller`?

Comment: This is handled by omniauth and I can't find a controller in the source of the lib. I fixed it by writing my own middleware that intercepts appropriate requests and adds headers.